# How to add proxy VM params to all maven calls in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, proxy, maven-3

I have IntelliJ IDEA 15 on a system that can only reach out to the internet using a proxy.

Therefore, I can configure Maven->Importing and Maven->Runner settings to include the

`-DproxyXXXX=YYYY`

VM options. This works just fine for all the maven goals that I initiate from the IDE

BUT: When I create a new maven project from an **archetype**, IDEA doesn't seem to add those VM options to the maven call that should set up the project according to the archetype.

My question is: How can I configure IntelliJ IDEA 15 for all projects so that it will always add those VM options?

The answer from JJF didn't work.

To clarify: This is what IntelliJ IDEA's maven outputs for a new project with webapp archetype:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java" "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files
(x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" 
"-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
15.0.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
15.0.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar"
org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=15.0.3
-DinteractiveMode=false -DgroupId=test3 -DartifactId=test3 -Dversion=1.0-
SNAPSHOT -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes
-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DarchetypeVersion=RELEASE
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:RELEASE:generate
```

and this should be added automatically:

```
-DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -DproxyPort=8080
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution

You don't need to have any maven settings in IntelliJ as long as you have a settings.xml (usually in your .m2 folder) which contains the proxies section:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</host>
      <port>8080</port>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>          
  ...
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got to File|Settings|Build, Execution, Deployment|Build Tools|Maven|Runner.  There is a section in that dialog that allows you to define properties.  I defined a test property there and confirmed IJ adds that to the Maven command line when I generate a new Maven project.

Comment: If you mean this one: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gPPG9.png it's supposed to be only for the current project (not for new ones). But I'll give it a try tomorrow when I get back to work

Comment: That's the one I meant.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work ... I'll edit my original post accordingly